# Tagged bucket not showing in AWS billing report

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to determine my AWS costs per bucket.  My bucket has a tag, as see on the bucket properties:

[image: Bucket Properties]

However, in the Cost Explorer, I am unable to see any tags.

[image: Cost Explorer]

Am I doing this right?  Where can I find info on how much that bucket is costing me?  I should also note that other services I'm using are tagged, and those don't appear in the Cost Explorer either.  I am an admin on the account, so it shouldn't be an issue of permissions.

Comment: Did you click the link "Why don't I see any tags?" in your screenshot?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes.  :-D  That's the first thing I did.  It takes me here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html  The documentation didn't indicate anything I haven't already done, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the page it should have linked you to.  You have to specify tags under preferences. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/configurecostallocreport.html